# Cannot extract certificate organization on some urls

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, rsa, x509

I want to be able to look up a website and provide the registered organization for that website. 
For example get_company("google.com") -> Google LLC. However, some websites that are signed and display their certificates correctly when opened in chrome don't work. For example "microsoft.com" is one that doesn't work. How can I look those other ones up?

```
import ssl
import socket
import OpenSSL


def get_certificate(host, port=443, timeout=10):
    context = ssl.create_default_context()
    conn = socket.create_connection((host, port))
    sock = context.wrap_socket(conn, server_hostname=host)
    sock.settimeout(timeout)
    try:
        der_cert = sock.getpeercert(True)
    finally:
        sock.close()
    return ssl.DER_cert_to_PEM_cert(der_cert)


def get_company(url):
    certificate = get_certificate(url)
    x509 = OpenSSL.crypto.load_certificate(OpenSSL.crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, certificate)
    return dict(x509.get_subject().get_components())[b'O']
```

EDIT:
Just to clarify, I am not interested in certificates made by Authorities like Let's Encrypt and I can filter them. They are unrelated to the question. The specific example I posted was because when I go to microsoft.com in Google Chrome I can see the subject field contains the organization.

Comment: *The specific example I posted was because when I go to microsoft.com in Google Chrome I can see the subject field contains the organization.*  Oh?  And what is the **exact** URL displayed in your browser when you do that?

Comment: https://www.microsoft.com/de-ch/ I am getting redirected to their specific resolved portal. I guess I should check for redirects in the https request and then access the cert. Gonna report back unless you have an idea how to solve. Thx!

Comment: But your script doesn't get redirected.  It pulls the cert from port 443 on the "microsoft.com" server.  That's not the same as port 443 on the "www.microsoft.com" server.  The certificate on "microsoft.com" has no "O" component in the subject DN.

Comment: I was responding to the browser stuff you mentioned. I was saying that maybe I should extend the script to look at the whole response and parse the code for a redirect first and then pull the cert after a redirect or if no redirect. Do you know of a better way?

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple *validation types* of X.509 certificates. Those specify which informations are part of the certificate (and thus validated by the CA issuing the certificate).

- **Domain Validated (DV)**: The subject of those certificates contains exactly one value: The domain. Those are very common these days, since that's what you get from Let's Encrypt
- **Organization Validated (OV)**: In addition to the domain, the certificate's subject also contains information about the certificate's owner. Usually just an organization name, sometimes also an actualy name or an organizational unit (OU).

The certificate you have problem with, is probably a DV certificate which simply does not have any organization information in its subject (which you are trying to parse).

Comment: This information is obviously in the certificate though. If i run the shell command:
curl --insecure -v https://microsoft.com 2>&1 | awk 'BEGIN { cert=0 } /^\* SSL connection/ { cert=1 } /^\*/ { if (cert) print }'
I can see the organization listed there

Comment: Please add the output of `openssl x509 -text` to your question.

Answer (score 1):

The certificate currently used on `microsoft.com` is:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            78:00:0f:e6:92:e4:bd:9e:fe:63:c5:71:67:00:00:00:0f:e6:92
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 4
        Validity
            Not Before: Feb  5 20:30:44 2020 GMT
            Not After : Feb  5 20:30:44 2022 GMT
        Subject: CN=microsoft.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:f1:1c:98:26:23:0f:fe:d2:ab:5d:a0:81:07:06:
                    ed:48:49:1b:8e:56:04:bb:de:80:df:06:6f:5a:5a:
                    96:3d:80:1e:3b:7a:aa:9d:c7:43:a0:fa:75:89:a9:
                    38:3c:20:52:cd:43:47:32:43:eb:ad:e7:50:37:b1:
                    3a:53:d1:2d:54:b2:4d:f4:1f:fb:16:ab:bb:50:53:
                    d5:b2:71:2b:a9:0c:fa:77:45:a6:fe:62:74:e1:e3:
                    cd:28:17:52:5c:4c:45:0d:7e:65:f8:44:9e:0f:9e:
                    34:1c:5d:e8:f0:b2:4f:1c:2c:9c:8b:a1:ae:74:a1:
                    1d:d8:2e:fb:10:3d:45:fd:02:cf:1f:d4:c8:8b:d5:
                    18:01:64:c0:ee:01:68:e0:db:da:79:5e:57:ff:a0:
                    a6:64:95:cf:68:4b:36:58:16:45:b0:0d:12:23:11:
                    e0:04:ae:e6:fc:5f:71:29:ff:60:9e:e4:6d:ef:e3:
                    2e:1d:28:e9:1c:23:8c:33:27:f4:33:f6:56:fb:f1:
                    b4:fc:55:96:61:0f:fe:a7:84:e7:c0:3b:84:0d:69:
                    ef:4c:da:83:05:08:81:68:97:d7:34:af:50:0b:78:
                    92:77:fe:8b:75:25:e5:57:51:bb:5a:25:2b:62:89:
                    da:83:69:d8:8f:ff:ce:cb:56:63:1f:2d:0f:23:48:
                    27:ad
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            S/MIME Capabilities:
......0...`.H.e...*0...`.H.e...-0...`.H.e....0...`.H.e....0...+....0
..*.H..
            1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2:
                ...i.g.u.......X......gp
.....p..w......F0D. $...Um...v......*2..>*./m\5.*3... v..^.|...$8.....P....b.e...UD....v."EE.YU$V.?./..m..#&c..K.]..\n......p..w......G0E. jFy............./9?4z..d....F....!..H..v.GN.........rc.....wb6...k..v.U.....6.J...W<S...8xp%../..........p..v......G0E.!..{r...GS7...[.....].~7.P...4..Ev. LzM...4
......yj+...
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10:
                0.0
..+.......0
..+.......
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7:
                0/.'+.....7.....u...........a...`.]...B...z..d...
            Authority Information Access:
                CA Issuers - URI:http://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/Microsoft%20IT%20TLS%20CA%204.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.msocsp.com

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                89:47:51:EA:1F:28:84:F0:D5:35:E4:97:C7:53:D6:82:D0:BE:C0:46
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:microsoft.com, DNS:s.microsoft.com, DNS:ga.microsoft.com, DNS:mi.microsoft.com, DNS:grv.microsoft.com, DNS:hup.microsoft.com, DNS:mac.microsoft.com, DNS:mkb.microsoft.com, DNS:pme.microsoft.com, DNS:pmi.microsoft.com, DNS:rss.microsoft.com, DNS:sar.microsoft.com, DNS:tco.microsoft.com, DNS:ieak.microsoft.com, DNS:mac2.microsoft.com, DNS:mcsp.microsoft.com, DNS:shop.microsoft.com, DNS:spur.microsoft.com, DNS:build.microsoft.com, DNS:itpro.microsoft.com, DNS:mango.microsoft.com, DNS:music.microsoft.com, DNS:pymes.microsoft.com, DNS:store.microsoft.com, DNS:aether.microsoft.com, DNS:alerts.microsoft.com, DNS:design.microsoft.com, DNS:garage.microsoft.com, DNS:gigjam.microsoft.com, DNS:ignite.microsoft.com, DNS:msctec.microsoft.com, DNS:online.microsoft.com, DNS:stream.microsoft.com, DNS:tpmsec.microsoft.com, DNS:afflink.microsoft.com, DNS:connect.microsoft.com, DNS:develop.microsoft.com, DNS:domains.microsoft.com, DNS:example.microsoft.com, DNS:madeira.microsoft.com, DNS:msdnisv.microsoft.com, DNS:mspress.microsoft.com, DNS:quantum.microsoft.com, DNS:sponsor.microsoft.com, DNS:wwwbeta.microsoft.com, DNS:business.microsoft.com, DNS:empresas.microsoft.com, DNS:learning.microsoft.com, DNS:msdnwiki.microsoft.com, DNS:pinpoint.microsoft.com, DNS:snackbox.microsoft.com, DNS:sponsors.microsoft.com, DNS:stationq.microsoft.com, DNS:aistories.microsoft.com, DNS:community.microsoft.com, DNS:crawlmsdn.microsoft.com, DNS:messenger.microsoft.com, DNS:minecraft.microsoft.com, DNS:backoffice.microsoft.com, DNS:enterprise.microsoft.com, DNS:iotcentral.microsoft.com, DNS:pinunblock.microsoft.com, DNS:reroute443.microsoft.com, DNS:communities.microsoft.com, DNS:explore-smb.microsoft.com, DNS:expressions.microsoft.com, DNS:ondernemers.microsoft.com, DNS:techacademy.microsoft.com, DNS:terraserver.microsoft.com, DNS:communities2.microsoft.com, DNS:connectevent.microsoft.com, DNS:dataplatform.microsoft.com, DNS:entrepreneur.microsoft.com, DNS:hxd.research.microsoft.com, DNS:mspartnerira.microsoft.com, DNS:oemcommunity.microsoft.com, DNS:real-stories.microsoft.com, DNS:www.formspro.microsoft.com, DNS:futuredecoded.microsoft.com, DNS:powerautomate.microsoft.com, DNS:smallbusiness.microsoft.com, DNS:upgradecenter.microsoft.com, DNS:learnanalytics.microsoft.com, DNS:onlinelearning.microsoft.com, DNS:businesscentral.microsoft.com, DNS:cloud-immersion.microsoft.com, DNS:analyticspartner.microsoft.com, DNS:businessplatform.microsoft.com, DNS:explore-security.microsoft.com, DNS:kleinunternehmen.microsoft.com, DNS:partnercommunity.microsoft.com, DNS:explore-marketing.microsoft.com, DNS:innovationcontest.microsoft.com, DNS:partnerincentives.microsoft.com, DNS:phoenixcataloguat.microsoft.com, DNS:szkolyprzyszlosci.microsoft.com, DNS:www.powerautomate.microsoft.com, DNS:successionplanning.microsoft.com, DNS:lumiaconversationsuk.microsoft.com, DNS:successionplanninguat.microsoft.com, DNS:businessmobilitycenter.microsoft.com, DNS:skypeandteams.fasttrack.microsoft.com, DNS:www.microsoftdlapartnerow.microsoft.com, DNS:commercialappcertification.microsoft.com, DNS:www.skypeandteams.fasttrack.microsoft.com
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://mscrl.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/crl/Microsoft%20IT%20TLS%20CA%204.crl
                  URI:http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/crl/Microsoft%20IT%20TLS%20CA%204.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies:
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.42.1
                  CPS: http://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps

            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:7A:7B:8C:C1:CF:E7:A0:CA:1C:D4:6B:FA:FB:E1:33:C3:0F:1A:A2:9D

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        1f:d8:61:7a:61:9e:d0:15:f9:4b:72:e4:33:e9:13:0c:7b:75:
        c4:5b:06:19:97:dd:f7:d3:c9:2f:15:2c:ee:83:46:bd:8a:d0:
        8a:6c:bc:5e:74:d2:53:80:58:17:ea:fd:d8:83:01:0e:d8:24:
        b5:ee:34:de:5d:bb:d2:16:65:af:fd:59:89:38:c1:af:c0:cf:
        e7:31:76:fb:22:b9:6f:f7:b6:91:54:2d:c9:da:81:cb:8f:84:
        b4:0c:8b:c6:f4:5e:6c:65:a3:ec:c3:be:02:29:8f:67:d3:ef:
        84:58:8f:18:75:0a:bb:97:63:1e:51:b2:1a:35:11:12:61:45:
        26:29:69:08:19:d3:b8:07:96:f0:ff:00:19:40:5e:80:30:83:
        c1:91:81:bb:64:f7:16:df:9f:fc:82:a2:3d:2e:f2:f9:46:60:
        e4:95:ef:41:2b:69:b6:f6:7f:8d:69:bf:82:72:01:d5:d9:34:
        8e:f4:70:67:92:8b:ea:34:b5:cb:b1:b4:71:d4:05:05:a8:d4:
        b6:56:c4:0e:5e:94:05:ce:48:72:54:52:d7:67:03:dd:fc:5b:
        1d:5d:27:09:65:f1:d3:ee:8c:36:84:35:28:89:26:88:ae:35:
        6e:ee:96:64:51:b6:09:0c:d7:5d:d9:60:e2:fb:31:5d:d5:8f:
        e6:2e:0c:0b:00:f5:24:27:48:b3:1e:8b:ee:f3:73:8e:82:a9:
        89:98:7a:ed:10:1d:52:ce:e5:b4:8a:d8:d8:d0:3a:b0:a7:0e:
        da:15:7b:67:f2:3b:35:12:96:ad:87:74:29:d1:b4:db:e6:87:
        37:6f:1d:6a:dc:02:aa:45:dd:15:e4:4a:9b:75:f3:22:4c:48:
        25:a1:90:1e:55:b7:df:35:8f:67:2f:73:94:69:f0:65:b9:ff:
        e8:12:83:ed:98:54:cb:a8:8e:06:7a:2a:45:09:ad:04:77:5b:
        3a:bf:ed:24:35:38:e6:4a:45:49:04:26:05:4e:eb:35:7d:26:
        c1:d5:dd:03:85:e6:a5:79:33:12:b2:53:ca:ab:67:fc:63:c7:
        94:5b:27:30:ce:a5:05:61:f7:62:65:26:a0:d8:9e:3c:dd:35:
        4d:51:0c:ab:ae:39:cb:94:b8:58:20:a0:ba:31:5f:e3:b7:d8:
        b0:15:15:ec:ee:78:8a:e9:a8:62:ca:02:38:df:6e:dd:34:22:
        7f:4f:96:f9:96:10:e7:5e:12:45:df:ed:6d:36:e8:a4:c1:af:
        63:3c:ac:3b:f0:aa:bf:44:a5:d7:5c:02:c0:ce:56:58:c5:77:
        f5:58:45:9a:64:3d:b2:a7:5f:97:d5:25:d2:e8:40:86:4b:bf:
        1c:09:6a:d2:04:d7:d2:a4
```

Notice `Subject: CN=microsoft.com` . The subject name contains *only* the CommonName attribute, not the Organization attribute. And as with essentially all modern website (HTTPS) certs, and many other SSL/TLS certs also, the Subject field is a legacy value that isn't actually used to identify the subject(s) of the cert; the `SubjectAlternativeName` *extension* is used instead.

OTOH the *CA* that issued this cert is also part (a different part) of Microsoft:

```
Issuer: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 4
```

which does have an Organization attribute identifying Microsoft. However this is rare; very few companies run their own CAs. For example, the current certificate on `stackoverflow.com` is

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            03:d5:35:ed:f0:9f:bb:da:42:c1:0c:e8:c6:33:d5:39:38:d9
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, O=Let's Encrypt, CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
        Validity
            Not Before: Jan 23 07:00:28 2020 GMT
            Not After : Apr 22 07:00:28 2020 GMT
        Subject: CN=*.stackexchange.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:9a:32:f8:05:bf:e1:14:7c:7c:39:f4:ce:37:c6:
                    ab:27:e2:7f:6d:73:68:8a:87:a2:c6:1e:f1:bd:39:
                    a3:52:86:99:a8:2d:45:91:e3:f6:ee:ea:ed:0b:ce:
                    6a:a9:30:94:97:83:5e:78:d9:8c:db:1a:e2:bc:e0:
                    ee:b2:b9:f9:b6:80:5a:e3:45:16:b2:fb:42:b7:ca:
                    e9:57:6d:87:fa:4a:44:6b:0b:5c:b4:12:63:17:a9:
                    13:2e:fd:85:0c:09:dd:43:c7:78:60:c6:d1:c2:b7:
                    56:61:d4:9e:72:b7:ea:64:5b:68:0f:d1:b4:5e:73:
                    08:6d:a5:ee:49:4f:e1:e6:d7:83:bd:4e:19:1a:e4:
                    4c:86:11:30:3a:a5:60:e9:fe:32:40:e1:be:8d:04:
                    80:28:a0:7a:7f:37:85:84:29:46:d3:93:8c:21:a1:
                    f6:cf:00:bd:dc:96:df:0c:94:c8:a3:b0:41:6d:1e:
                    4a:86:c0:51:c3:9a:7a:8c:55:e3:de:86:7d:1f:3d:
                    fb:0d:1f:83:ef:23:f6:f3:2a:a2:ff:47:87:a9:cd:
                    8e:d5:f2:3c:84:1b:88:34:86:63:15:a6:5d:c3:5b:
                    e8:04:65:20:88:d9:70:4d:d2:31:45:04:38:fa:b9:
                    3d:04:69:70:19:91:ef:65:79:18:a6:63:50:27:df:
                    87:9b
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            X509v3 Key Usage: critical
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment
            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Server Authentication, TLS Web Client Authentication
            X509v3 Basic Constraints: critical
                CA:FALSE
            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                F0:61:88:B2:8F:1D:EB:1E:FF:68:BC:BD:7A:D0:AF:9C:0C:34:09:18
            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:A8:4A:6A:63:04:7D:DD:BA:E6:D1:39:B7:A6:45:65:EF:F3:A8:EC:A1

            Authority Information Access:
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.int-x3.letsencrypt.org
                CA Issuers - URI:http://cert.int-x3.letsencrypt.org/

            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:*.askubuntu.com, DNS:*.blogoverflow.com, DNS:*.mathoverflow.net, DNS:*.meta.stackexchange.com, DNS:*.meta.stackoverflow.com, DNS:*.serverfault.com, DNS:*.sstatic.net, DNS:*.stackexchange.com, DNS:*.stackoverflow.com, DNS:*.stackoverflow.email, DNS:*.superuser.com, DNS:askubuntu.com, DNS:blogoverflow.com, DNS:mathoverflow.net, DNS:openid.stackauth.com, DNS:serverfault.com, DNS:sstatic.net, DNS:stackapps.com, DNS:stackauth.com, DNS:stackexchange.com, DNS:stackoverflow.blog, DNS:stackoverflow.com, DNS:stackoverflow.email, DNS:stacksnippets.net, DNS:superuser.com
            X509v3 Certificate Policies:
                Policy: 2.23.140.1.2.1
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.44947.1.1.1
                  CPS: http://cps.letsencrypt.org

            1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2:
                ......v......... N.f.+..% gk..p..IS-...^...o.j.......G0E. Gt...N...O.wDE...~.P.~s..........!.....X....3.uW....z..*.....X......v.^.s..V...6H}.I.2z.........u..qEX...o.j.......G0E. Q...IB...\,.d.q3.T.2.v...z8..0...!.....6....uBJ.......xj....T...Vc.
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        17:cd:09:07:27:8f:14:2e:bc:f0:55:3d:f2:6f:dc:76:27:1e:
        ed:55:95:66:64:87:a0:b6:6c:dd:71:e1:d2:cb:f6:44:c4:25:
        f7:b3:5f:be:69:16:6b:f1:8b:63:b7:9f:07:73:47:9b:da:d5:
        be:b1:6b:7b:c2:2a:7e:cc:e0:37:29:0d:c7:39:30:0f:84:2a:
        a9:28:3d:93:a7:1d:33:7a:f0:72:73:b7:72:2e:2a:ab:96:65:
        65:f5:af:0b:70:55:13:c7:2c:96:59:0a:b2:ef:c1:14:a2:51:
        f6:c7:b3:ef:89:db:2c:7d:a7:8b:ac:17:c2:44:8e:b8:0a:12:
        27:ff:bb:de:e7:5d:44:24:c0:1f:79:9b:3e:b1:65:a5:58:98:
        cc:f5:ab:3d:e8:8a:70:db:1c:90:14:40:c5:1f:51:4b:b4:7a:
        3c:2e:4b:c8:5e:2b:5d:86:42:2d:f1:e9:64:2a:53:00:10:88:
        fc:7f:41:bd:8b:91:cc:2d:66:b2:af:ea:70:dd:61:cf:a5:c3:
        37:3c:56:a5:db:fc:18:e4:ad:af:0d:42:82:cb:22:d6:d6:93:
        54:5d:89:0e:03:d9:49:9f:80:ee:ab:f4:41:b1:0a:1f:82:4b:
        94:a5:9e:a0:0d:e4:1e:ad:24:ba:1c:91:96:aa:82:df:12:76:
        9e:54:04:55
```

which as you see also has only CommonName in Subject, and the real identities in SAN instead, but is issued by LetsEncrypt (exactly the case @mat referred to), so the Issuer Organization is Let's Encrypt. Do you want to report that stackoverflow and stackexchange etc are part of Let's Encrypt?

In general certificates are not required to be owned by an organization at all, much less a 'registered' one, and if one is, it isn't necessarily required to have that organization name contained in the cert.

**ADDED:** Okay, as noted in comments accessing microsoft.com with HTTPS (not just TLS) redirects to www.microsoft.com, which both your python and my OpenSSL ignored but browsers of course follow -- and (my) Chrome seriously confuses because it still shows microsoft.com/$path in the address bar. www.microsoft.com is on Akamai so you will get a different server than me and *may* get a different cert, but the cert I get is:

```
Certificate:
    Data:
        Version: 3 (0x2)
        Serial Number:
            2d:00:0c:37:15:62:c4:1d:93:94:08:7f:68:00:00:00:0c:37:15
        Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        Issuer: C=US, ST=Washington, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft IT, CN=Microsoft IT TLS CA 5
        Validity
            Not Before: Oct 21 22:04:04 2019 GMT
            Not After : Oct 21 22:04:04 2021 GMT
        Subject: C=US, ST=WA, L=Redmond, O=Microsoft Corporation, OU=Microsoft Corporation, CN=www.microsoft.com
        Subject Public Key Info:
            Public Key Algorithm: rsaEncryption
                Public-Key: (2048 bit)
                Modulus:
                    00:d3:10:ad:42:cd:4c:1d:02:b1:0e:6f:fb:c3:3a:
                    a7:6c:ef:fb:d0:d7:21:90:b4:06:1a:65:83:41:72:
                    1d:bb:2b:0d:ff:5c:a9:df:b5:dd:cd:56:3e:ed:61:
                    ee:cc:84:8d:54:f9:b9:27:c6:14:b1:ee:6e:2d:8b:
                    b3:f3:b7:a9:b1:42:24:d9:fc:a7:a0:62:1c:68:b1:
                    dd:ec:38:48:a4:5e:02:55:cc:40:af:87:43:2f:77:
                    a6:9d:ae:f8:b4:d1:c5:1e:43:3d:1d:96:45:24:bb:
                    13:00:8e:21:6c:f8:55:fb:3a:07:f8:c6:df:2e:6f:
                    88:4a:64:f1:81:f3:9b:c3:9d:04:34:38:75:61:2f:
                    d2:2e:51:b6:07:86:68:7c:12:80:c4:75:1f:a8:83:
                    e9:63:ee:ee:4e:2a:dd:d8:11:69:ed:81:b9:df:57:
                    57:7a:e9:4e:7d:91:fa:79:0e:0e:13:ff:31:63:ab:
                    3f:e5:53:72:86:05:68:23:d1:8a:31:1f:c2:86:7e:
                    ea:b6:61:f1:50:b2:6e:d0:e0:c0:c9:9d:1d:8f:35:
                    46:f0:c2:b2:b9:26:57:5c:46:7d:bb:a3:94:95:67:
                    16:81:e7:96:ec:77:21:d6:2f:41:9b:1b:92:68:20:
                    85:a0:f2:91:89:5c:a6:06:7c:04:43:11:58:d6:8a:
                    30:4f
                Exponent: 65537 (0x10001)
        X509v3 extensions:
            1.3.6.1.4.1.11129.2.4.2:
                ...h.f.v..\./.w0".T..0.V..M..3.../ ..N.d....m.bqq.....G0E.!.......L.O.:D.9.F...
.e..$..<..... ..s....'}..o..+....EL.1bN.W.&....u.U.....6.J...W<S...8xp%../..........m.br......F0D. Z&..b.>...r....j-.D.2nH.q{.D.&... E...........D.9.gp.iE(.CO.+B2.~S.u.}>.....Uh$....R.y+..x...j.h.~".....m.bq......F0D. d..z%.t..W.C.}E+.....~...>).1.O.. h....%<..N..9w...VY.......x...fC
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.10:
                0.0
..+.......0
..+.......
            1.3.6.1.4.1.311.21.7:
                0/.'+.....7.....u...........a...`.]...B...z..d...
            Authority Information Access:
                CA Issuers - URI:http://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/Microsoft%20IT%20TLS%20CA%205.crt
                OCSP - URI:http://ocsp.msocsp.com

            X509v3 Subject Key Identifier:
                F6:AB:BF:05:1E:41:B7:70:E9:91:F8:1A:95:6E:F6:0C:2B:09:FB:95
            X509v3 Key Usage:
                Digital Signature, Key Encipherment, Data Encipherment
            X509v3 Subject Alternative Name:
                DNS:wwwqa.microsoft.com, DNS:www.microsoft.com, DNS:staticview.microsoft.com, DNS:i.s-microsoft.com, DNS:microsoft.com, DNS:c.s-microsoft.com, DNS:privacy.microsoft.com
            X509v3 CRL Distribution Points:

                Full Name:
                  URI:http://mscrl.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/crl/Microsoft%20IT%20TLS%20CA%205.crl
                  URI:http://crl.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/crl/Microsoft%20IT%20TLS%20CA%205.crl

            X509v3 Certificate Policies:
                Policy: 1.3.6.1.4.1.311.42.1
                  CPS: http://www.microsoft.com/pki/mscorp/cps

            X509v3 Authority Key Identifier:
                keyid:08:FE:25:9F:74:EA:87:04:C2:BC:BB:8E:A8:38:5F:33:C6:D1:6C:65

            X509v3 Extended Key Usage:
                TLS Web Client Authentication, TLS Web Server Authentication
    Signature Algorithm: sha256WithRSAEncryption
        75:63:1a:5b:73:4e:3f:96:2b:e3:b4:a8:c3:55:19:34:b3:26:
        0e:5c:4d:8f:3f:bc:0d:c1:e2:7e:54:1f:2a:c2:26:3a:fb:3f:
        51:f9:54:ac:c1:97:1b:ba:c7:e7:b3:5b:25:9f:67:62:94:93:
        1d:6c:52:25:f2:ac:18:f7:37:a6:07:39:47:5b:31:67:10:db:
        ea:50:6e:5c:43:7d:36:f8:49:32:63:f0:06:4c:8a:24:00:27:
        8d:83:7a:c8:23:59:3f:85:fa:74:13:8e:35:6f:2e:a2:99:27:
        17:e0:91:1c:36:5d:4a:23:1a:16:21:38:7d:50:9e:d0:ba:ce:
        f7:46:f8:44:e3:ec:45:5f:33:1e:7e:7b:8b:50:75:eb:d9:f5:
        72:ab:0b:5e:b3:07:bc:ad:17:9e:ee:eb:c2:bb:ef:77:90:5b:
        39:aa:a6:ec:3a:e0:c0:96:14:93:45:1c:88:d1:1f:73:23:76:
        74:d4:5c:0b:1a:1f:59:07:55:19:0a:af:6a:0a:ad:8f:20:c2:
        9b:f1:09:e8:32:76:91:69:65:18:78:da:b9:cf:08:90:c6:94:
        78:27:9d:4d:8a:61:0a:11:1c:91:7a:11:05:98:a4:66:dc:8b:
        d2:86:63:eb:b8:8a:86:de:a6:9b:87:d2:4f:ec:74:66:eb:b9:
        c1:dc:d4:a0:24:d0:b0:d4:c7:57:41:92:6d:c5:48:45:c8:26:
        68:d8:b0:3f:ed:3e:96:b4:68:71:4a:e3:da:1f:fb:d8:84:0d:
        f0:f7:bf:f8:2a:c3:79:52:4d:94:a0:3d:81:63:65:fa:dd:45:
        fe:bd:c2:29:69:e4:10:dc:8d:50:24:e0:82:20:92:a2:37:58:
        f5:19:23:d6:b4:e2:78:fe:8c:48:15:19:05:67:f7:30:1e:57:
        22:e6:8b:39:33:b4:ff:08:4c:f3:7d:64:af:13:46:fe:4d:26:
        74:2a:43:b5:d2:af:08:a2:1c:01:1a:e4:28:cf:40:dd:3c:6d:
        56:93:9d:f1:ff:64:89:f7:06:68:fa:93:41:8a:fc:7f:18:6b:
        34:1f:3a:e2:ab:02:1b:5e:e8:f1:97:24:04:a5:bc:15:8e:47:
        fe:34:90:01:96:f5:a9:bc:2c:4d:b0:4c:5c:92:2b:d2:50:0f:
        c0:7e:cb:20:01:c9:27:2b:25:1b:45:f7:32:9d:00:46:e9:86:
        5a:a5:70:88:73:82:68:b5:ce:d6:24:90:5f:4c:16:e3:2a:3e:
        94:6c:56:38:db:ce:22:86:9d:d8:d7:9d:fd:fc:4c:eb:be:5f:
        11:50:be:af:e0:c8:e8:12:9b:b7:d0:a1:7c:85:e2:5d:e5:0b:
        a8:e6:42:df:2a:76:16:8f
```

which does have Organization (and Org Unit) in the Subject, as you want. This may or may not be true for other websites/companies.

Comment: Let's Encrypt issues are not very related to this post and are able to be handled. Please see my edit.